# Symfony javascript scoped to reusable Twig-fragment to add multiple list-items

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony 5.1 with webpack-encore.

I want to create a reusable Twig-fragment to be used in forms which should enable the user to do following workflow:

1. enter a string into a text-field
2. click "Add"-button/press enter
3. content of the text-field is added to an `<ul>`
4. focus goes back to the text-field

and so on...

So I started with a form-type like this.

```
[...]
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('compoundStrings', HiddenType::class)
        ->add('stringInput', TextType::class)
        ->add('addString', ButtonType::class, [
            'label' => 'Add'
        ])
    ;

    $builder->get('compoundStrings')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CompoundStringsToStringArrayTransformer());
}
```

where *compoundStrings* should be updated with each click on "Add" so that it will eventually hold all entered values in its value-attribute and can subsequently be processed when I handle the form.

My fragment looks still extremely basic right now as I am somewhat stuck at this point:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    {{ form_row(field.compoundStrings) }}
    {{ form_row(field.stringInput) }}
    {{ form_row(field.addString) }}
    <ul class="{{ field.vars.full_name }}-list"></ul>
</fieldset>
```

For my approach to work I would need some javascript to do the adding/removing to the 
and to update the value of the compoundStrings-field.

Is it possible to have the necessary JS scoped to the relevant fragment so I can possibly include it k times in a single form?

Comment: You could do something like that, but have you looked into [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)? It might suit your needs (you'll still need some custom js, though).

Comment: From the examples it doesn't look like it really fits my case. May be due to my lack of experience with symfony though. It looks as if it would be especially useful for relations to other entities. I am basically trying to find a good pattern for a form element to fill array-type properties.